# How to change case of the first letter of all variables in code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a big piece of code, where every title of variable begins with a capital letter.
What is the best way to manage the case of the first letter of every variable in code depending on the variable use?

Thank you for sharing your experience!

Comment: What do you mean by "depending on the context"? Which variables do you refer to? Only locals? Or also fields? Properties? Method-parameters?

Comment: I mean depending on the variable use, if it is a static variable, if it is a private field, or a public one, if it is a property or a method variable and etc.

Comment: So which ones *do* you want to update and *how*? ReSharper has such functionality, to check for naming-conventions and fix your code appropriately.

Comment: I would like to have all the variables cased after the next casing guideline: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms229043(v=vs.100)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385869/refactoring-a-whole-projects-variable-and-parameter-names has some useful pointers, infact this question is probably a duplicate of it

Comment: Thank you all, especially CaiusJard and HimBromBeere, I will use R# to solve this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resharper can do this. It has a set of (customisable) rules for variable names, and will highlight everything that breaks those rules. Right clicking on an error will give you a menu will give you the option to rename that variable, and also the option to fix all similar errors, either in the file, or the project, or the whole solution.

https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

By default Resharper will use camelCase for private variables and PascalCase for public variables, methods and properties.

[image]

Comment: So, if I set a custom rule for variable names in R#, it would be able to rename all variables according to how they were used?

Comment: @Kiseki You can define your own naming-conventions and R# will rename all your variables according to those rules.

Answer (score 1):

In visual studio, you right click on the variable (any occurrence of it) and choose RENAME

Then start typing your new name and watch all the instances change

Comment: That´s pretty cumbersome if you want to do this for all variables in the code.

Comment: Does it not work? Does it fail to do what the OP asks? It answers the question - no restriction was placed such as "the process must modify every occurrence of every different variable in one hit" amd if the question is changed to invalidate the answer, I can remove it.. (I also often find that in many cases such as these, trying for an hour to develop an ingenous solution is slower than the 20 minutes it'll take to repeatedly use the rename fucntion, especially if one gets more into the keyboard shortcuts..)

Comment: @CaiusJard, OP wants to change ALL variables at once, not each one individually.

Comment: Well, it gets the job done, but its completely un-practical. So, no, your answer isn´t whrong, it´s just useless.

Comment: @RobinBennett I didn't read it that way, but i see your perspective. So are you gonna post a link to a magic tool that changes all the `m_Xyz` to `_xyz`? I'd like one of those too :)

Comment: @CaiusJard, I was asking for a way to change case of the first letter of every variable in code, and changing it using like this would take way too much time

Comment: @Caius_Jard so the answer is "No, there is no such tool"?

Comment: @CaiusJard, good point, I'll add a link to my answer. Resharper takes a while to get used to (it annoyed me at first) but it's really powerful and has many useful features when you dig into what it can do.

Comment: @Kiseki Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385869/refactoring-a-whole-projects-variable-and-parameter-names - the best I know of without buying resharper is as i've explained. RB and HBB seem to have resharper and outline that it makes the process easier but not fully automatic. R#r is a commercial, paid for product but every dev I know who's used it says it's worth it (and inarguably MS do build R#r functions into visual studio which is an endorsement in itself)